# graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph

Tags: acumatica

I'm needing to adjust some of the field attributes for the Location.VCashAccountID field on the Vendors screen - AP303000.  When I put the code below into a customization DLL, it compiles fine and there are not apparent issues on the screen.  However, when I try to publish the customization project with the DLL included, I get an error.

Code:

```
 public class VendorMaintDefLocationExtExt : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint.DefLocationExt, 
 VendorMaint>
{
    public void _(Events.CacheAttached<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location.vCashAccountID> e) { }
}
```

Error:
"Method Boolean DoValidateAddresses(PX.Objects.CR.Extensions.ValidateAddressesDelegate) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph"

[image]

What am I missing?

TIA!

Comment: Two questions for you so I can complete the proposed solution.

1. What field attributes are you trying to adjust?
2. What Build of Acumatica are you trying to make the modification within?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the CashAccount attribute.  This is in 21.208.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following implementation will override the vCashAccount attribute on AP303000

```
public class AAVendorMaintDefLocationExtExtension : PXGraphExtension<DefLocationExt, DefContactAddressExt, VendorMaint>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "I am override")]
    public void _(Events.CacheAttached<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location.vCashAccountID> e) { }
}
```

You will also require the following references

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using static PX.Objects.AP.VendorMaint;
```

The result can be seen in the snip below

[image: attribute]

The main difficulty in this task was the multitude of graph extensions utilized by the page. Though it's a beneficial design to encapsulate functionality it can be *finnicky* to determine which order they should be declared in a new extension.

Comment: Josh - Thanks for sending this over!  I'm still getting this error when trying to deploy my project - "Method Boolean DoValidateAddresses(PX.Objects.CR.Extensions.ValidateAddressesDelegate) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph".  I have my code in a dll which I have set to build into the bin directory.  The code functions fine in Acumatica but, when I try to deploy it catches this error.  goofy.  right now, I have it set with no attributes on the cacheattached() - still error on deploy.

Comment: That's interesting as I had been able to replicate your original problem but this implementation had overcome it, I'll look again today and update.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have updated my answer after verifying page load and customization publish.

Comment: Josh - that got it.  Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

You're graph extension extends VendorMaint.DefLocationExt which contains DoValidateAddresses.  Try just extending VendorMaint.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  I tried that and it will resolve the publish error but, my changes don't take effect on the field.  I'm trying to replace the CashAccount attribute on the Location.VCashAccountID.  If I just extend the VendorMaint graph, my changes won't take effect but, if I leave it how I have it above, they do but, the deployment fails.  It's a pickle!