# InventoryItemCurySettings Custom Field Never Update on Event handler

Tags: acumatica

Version 22.207

I have added a custom field to the InventoryItemCurySettings table and I'm trying to update it based on the Item Class that is selected.  So, I've added a FieldUpdated event override to the Graph extension as below.

The problem is that my custom field is never updated.  I've verified that settings variable has a record.  Also, I've tried both the Update() method and the SetValue() and SetValueExt() methods to try to update the field - it's never updated.

```
public class MyInventoryItemMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    public void _(Events.FieldUpdated<InventoryItem, InventoryItem.itemClassID> e, PXFieldUpdated baseMethod)
    {
        
        baseMethod(e.Cache, e.Args);
        
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        InventoryItemCurySettings settings = Base.ItemCurySettings.Current; 
        Base.ItemCurySettings.Cache.SetValue<InventoryItemCurySettingsExt.usrCustom>(settings, "Test");

        //InventoryItemCurySettingsExt settingsExt = settings.GetExtension<InventoryItemCurySettingsExt>();
        //settingsExt.UsrCustom = "Test";
        //Base.ItemCurySettings.Update(settings);

        
    }
 
}
```

Any insights would be great.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531520/graph-extension-is-marked-as-pxoverride-but-the-original-method-with-such-nam/71561037#71561037) the underlying issue was other graph extensions that were already in the mix.

Since your PXGraphExtension did not utilize the highest level extension already declared from the entry graph a.k.a. `CurySettingsExtension` your custom field value was being overridden by the logic within that extension.

By creating a PXGraphExtension of the highest level and declaring a row updated event within we can then set the value of the custom field in the `InventoryItemCurySettings` DAC and have the value be persisted to the database.

```
public class CurySettingsExtensionExtension : PXGraphExtension<CurySettingsExtension<NonStockItemMaint, InventoryItem, InventoryItemCurySettings>, NonStockItemMaint>
{
    public void __(Events.RowUpdated<InventoryItem> e)
    {
        if(e.Row is InventoryItem row)
        {
            Base.ItemCurySettings.SetValueExt<InventoryItemCurySettingsExtension.usrCustom>(Base.GetCurySettings(row.InventoryID), "Testing");
        }
    }
}
```

Result below :

[image]