# Can you Override a PXHidden class?

Tags: acumatica

I need to override 2 functions in the StatementCreateBO class. When I do a normal [PXOverride] on the functions I get the following error

[image]

Here is the code I have been using. To test I regenerate a statement on the Print statement screen AR503500. The error shows in the trace.

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class StatementCreateBO_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AR.StatementCreateBO>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        public delegate void RegenerateLastStatementDelegate(StatementCycleProcessBO graph, ARStatementCycle aCycle);
        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void RegenerateLastStatement(StatementCycleProcessBO graph, ARStatementCycle aCycle, RegenerateLastStatementDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod(graph, aCycle);
        }

        public delegate void ProcessCyclesDelegate(StatementCycleProcessBO graph, ARStatementCycle aCycle);
        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void ProcessCycles(StatementCycleProcessBO graph, ARStatementCycle aCycle, RegenerateLastStatementDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod(graph, aCycle);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks similiar to this issue I helped an inidividual resolve : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531520/graph-extension-is-marked-as-pxoverride-but-the-original-method-with-such-nam/71561037#71561037

Comment: What build of Acumatica is this within?

Comment: This is in Build 22.101.0085

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is the wrong graph being extended?

**StatementCycleProcessBO** contains RegenerateLastStatement and ProcessCycles methods.

In the code you have posted you are trying to extend **StatementCreateBO** which does not have these methods which will result in the error message you are receiving.